# Odds of picking letters from the alphabet

Tags: probability

I want to know how to work out the odds of randomly picking specific letters for a given word from the alphabet.

1. Let's call the random word: "bobdylan"
2. Total letters: 8
3. Total chances to randomly pick: 7 (since b appears twice)
4. With each pick, the chosen letter will be removed from the pool.
5. The order chosen does not matter

What I want to work out is the odds of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 correct letters.

What I have done is to write a program to randomly pick letters and I have found that it nearly always picks 1 - 4 correct letters in any given go with very few 0 correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of 7 distinct letters, we can partition the alphabet into 2 groups, one with correct letters (7) and wrong letters (26-7=19).

If we choose 7 letters and want x correct letters, we need x to be from the correct letters and 7-x to be from the wrong letters.

We note that the sample space if given by the fact that we are choosing 7 letters from the alphabet of 26.

That means, for any x $\leq 7$, the probability is:

$$ \frac{\binom{7}{x} \binom{19}{7-x}}{\binom{26}{7}}$$

Comment: So how do I know the actual maths for matching 7 correct letter? i.e. 1 in 200 chance?

Comment: @HappyCoder I gave the probability for matching all 7 correct letters in my answer., it isn't close to 1 in 200.  It is closer to 1 in 100000.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrased... you have an urn with $26$ balls (*representing the letters*), $7$ of which are gold (*representing the letters present in bobdylan*) and the remaining $19$ of which are red.  You ask what the **probability** (*not odds, related but different definition*) is that given the player picks $7$ balls that exactly $k$ of them are gold?  This follows the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

The probability of getting exactly $k$ gold balls will be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{7}{k}\binom{19}{7-k}}{\binom{26}{7}}$$

The probabilities themselves being:

$\begin{array}{l|l}Pr(X=k)&\dfrac{\binom{7}{k}\binom{19}{7-k}}{\binom{26}{7}}\\
\hline
Pr(X=0)&\approx 0.0766\\
Pr(X=1)&\approx 0.28873\\
Pr(X=2)&\approx 0.3712\\
\vdots
\\
Pr(X=7)&\approx 1.5\cdot 10^{-6}\end{array}$

The above uses the notation of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  $\binom{n}{k}$, read aloud as "$n$ choose $k$" is the number of $k$-kelement subsets of an $n$-element set.  We recognize that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  Here, $n!$ represents the number of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of an $n$-element set.  We recognize that $n! = n\times (n-1)!$ and $0!=1!=1$.  These together imply (*for natural $n$*) that $n! = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n i$, for example $3! = 1\times 2\times 3=6$ and $5! = 1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times 5=120$ and $6!=1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times 5\times 6 = 720$ etc...

Breaking down one of the entries of the above table in more detail then, we have for example:

$$Pr(X=0)=\dfrac{\binom{7}{0}\binom{19}{7-0}}{\binom{26}{7}} = \dfrac{\frac{7!}{0!7!}\cdot \frac{19!}{7!12!}}{\frac{26!}{7!19!}} = \dots$$

$n!$ grows incredibly large incredibly quickly and so we do not bother evaluating each individually and then multiplying them and dividing them by hand except for very small cases.  For example, if we were to try to calculate $\binom{26}{7}$ using and evaluating the factorials first as $\frac{26!}{7!19!}$ this would be $\binom{26}{7}=\dfrac{403291461126605635584000000}{5040\times 121645100408832000}$ which simplifies nicely to $657800$ but doing that by hand is not feasible.

Instead, plugging the above into a calculator such as [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(7+choose+0)(19+choose+7)%2F(26+choose+7)) we get after simplifications that:

$$Pr(X=0)=\frac{969}{12650}\approx 0.07660\dots$$

Comment: If k = 7, would this not be a division by zero? (7/7 x 19/0) / (26/7)

Comment: @happycoder those are binomial coefficients, *not fractions!*

Comment: @happycoder the binomial coefficient, $\binom{n}{k}$ (read aloud as "n choose k"), is the number of subsets of size k from an n- element set.  It is used in various counting problems like this one.  There is no division by zero going on.

Comment: Ok got it... how do I do the actual calculation? i.e, Pr(X=0) = 0.0766

Comment: @happycoder Pr(X=0) = (7 choose 0)(19 choose 7)/(26 choose 7).  To calculate binomial coefficients the most common way is as (n choose k)$=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ where the exclamation marks represent the factorial, $n!$ counting the number of permutations of n elements, i.e. the number of ways you can line n distinct elements in a row using each exactly once.  Note, $0!=1$ and $n!=(n-1)!\times n$ so you have for example $5!= 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=120$